# Hitting [return] after a div in TinyMCE creates another div. Do you know why and how to stop it?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-5

Default behavior of TinyMCE is that if I hit return at the end of a `heading`, it creates a new `p`, but if I hit return at the end of a `div`, it creates another `div`.

`headings` and `divs` are both block elements, and seem to have the exact same settings in tinyMCE defaults, so I don't understand why this happens, and I don't find a way to make it behave differently. I need the `div` to behave just like the `h1`.

Code pen: 
https://codepen.io/jacoping/pen/QWjQNxZ

Does anybody have a clue about why the div is behaving in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

In `tinyMCE.init`, add `forced_root_block : 'p'`. This will always insert `p` elements when you press enter.

As to why this was happening: Most users are more likely to insert a `p` after a `h1`, and are more likely to insert a `div` after another `div`. The program is being 'clever' and inserting the element that it thinks you're most likely to use next.

Comment: Thanks! But it does not seem to be a working solution.
https://codepen.io/jacoping/pen/OJyQjZN

Answer (score 0):

When you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after a heading, the behavior that word processors use (and people expect) is that you "leave" the heading and return to a normal block.  In word processors that is a regular paragraph (`<p></p>`).

TinyMCE mimics this behavior so when you press enter leaving a heading (or a list or a table, etc) it creates a "default root block".

A div is another type of default root block - just not one people choose to use often.  If you press enter at the end of a `<p>` or a `<div>` TinyMCE will simply give you another one of the same root block elements.

If you want to revert back to a paragraph when pressing enter at the end of the `<div>` you can use the `styleselect` dropdown to do that by selecting a different Block from the list.  In your example you have

```
style_formats: [
  { title: 'H1', block: 'h1' },
  { title: 'DIV', block: 'div' },
]
```

...which overrides the normal options in the list and removes any opportunity you have to switch to another block option like paragraph.  If you comment out that part of the configuration your select list will include a variety of block options so you can switch back to a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE provides an editor event called `NewBlock` that lets you detect when new blocks have been added to the editor in response to various things, including the user's pressing enter.  (Find it in the list of events [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/events/#editor-core-events).)  You can respond to that event by replacing the new block with a plain vanilla paragraph, like so:

```js
editor.on( 'NewBlock', event => {
    const paragraph = editor.dom.doc.createElement( 'p' )
    paragraph.innerHTML = '&nbsp;' // ensure it can receive the cursor
    event.newBlock.replaceWith( paragraph )
} )
```